# TableView not showing values in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to fix this, I searched 100 SO questions but no answer works.
I'm trying to populate the TableView on Initialize. My data is beeing loaded well, as shown in the console output and the tableView displays the 6 rows that should show, but with no values. I'm doing something wrong but i can't figure out what.

Would appreciate any help. Thank you!

```
public class spotStatusController {
private Connection con = connect();
@FXML
private TableView<ObservableList<String>> spotReport;
private ObservableList spotData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
@FXML
private TableColumn<ObservableList<String>,String> col;


@FXML
private void initialize(){
    try{

        java.sql.Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        String sql = "SELECT * from spot";
        java.sql.ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

        for(int i=0 ; i<rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++){
            col = new TableColumn<>(rs.getMetaData().getColumnName(i+1));

            col.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<ObservableList<String>,String>("s"));

            spotReport.getColumns().add(col);
            System.out.println("Column ["+i+"] ");
        }

        while (rs.next()){
            ObservableList row = FXCollections.observableArrayList();


            for (int i = 1; i <= rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++) {
                row.add(rs.getString(i));


            }
            System.out.println("Row [1] added "+row);

            spotData.add(row);
        }
        System.out.println(spotData);
        //spotReport.setItems(spotData);
        spotReport.getItems().setAll(spotData);

    }
    catch(SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}}
```

Console output:

```
Column [0] 
Column [1] 
Column [2] 
Row [1] added [4, t, null]
Row [1] added [5, t, null]
Row [1] added [1, t, null]
Row [1] added [6, t, null]
Row [1] added [3, t, null]
Row [1] added [2, f, 13]
[[4, t, null], [5, t, null], [1, t, null], [6, t, null], [3, t, null], [2,         
 f, 13]]
```

[Here image of the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPtB2.jpg)

Comment: `ObservableList` does not define a `sProperty()` or `getS()` method, so your `PropertyValueFactory` will not work.

Comment: @James_D so how do I make PropertyValueFactory in this case?

Comment: You can't use `PropertyValueFactory` in this case. Just implement the cell value factory yourself.